# SOAPUI how to create an assertion with a XML inside Json

Tags: soapui

I have a Get request that gives as response a Json. Inside the Json is a XML file.
How can I create Assertions on the XML part?

```
{
   "conversatie_id": "c69394b2-2403-4c3a-aaaf-4b0582482356",
   "retourXmlBericht": "<note><heading>Heading</heading><body>Message</body></note>"
}
```

Comment: I would probably approach this using some groovy script. I think you can have groovy script in assertions. Or you can have groovy script that is triggered when a response is received. 

in there you can probably extract the string that is your xml message and then parse that.

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but it should give you some ideas how to approach your issue. [SoapUI:Working with CDATA](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/working-with-cdata/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a groovy Script Assertion to parse the json and get the xml with JsonSlurper. Then use XmlHolder to get nodes value.

This is the groovy script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

//grab the json response
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)

assert jsonSlurper.retourXmlBericht  != null

//grab the xml extracted
def holder = new XmlHolder(jsonSlurper.retourXmlBericht)
def valueHeading = holder.getNodeValue("//note/heading")
def valueBody = holder.getNodeValue("//note/body")

assert valueHeading == "Heading"
assert valueBody == "Message"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the groovy script assertion works. Thanks for the script.